# Scheduled task not working in Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: vbscript, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, wsh

We have a Windows Script File X.wsf, which in turn will call Y.vbs. When we run X.wsf from the command window in Windows Server 2008 R2, either as "cscript X.wsf" or "X.wsf", it works fine. However, if we create a task in Windows Scheduler and trigger X.wsf, the only thing that we see is "Running" status, but nothing seems to happen. The task will remain in "Running" status forever, but we don't see anything happening.

Note that "Start In" in the task properties is already set to the folder containing X.wsf, and we also set it to run with SYSTEM and with "Run with highest privileges".

In Windows Server 2003, the same task works just fine. Also, we created a small .bat script and tested running it with a scheduled task in Windows Server 2008 R2, and it worked fine as well. So we suspect that Windows Scheduler must be behaving differently in Windows Server 2008 R2 for .wsf or .vbs files. Anyone know what the root cause is, and what is the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User,

I tried executing a wscript on a command session as well as a task session. Im able to execute from both the ways.

Make sure that you mention the correct path/filename in the trigger section. Also make sure that you provide the complete path of the switch

```
<Actions Context="Author">
  <Exec>
    <Command>C:\Windows\System32\wscript.exe</Command>
    <Arguments>u:\Scripts\test.vbs</Arguments>
  </Exec>
</Actions>
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: For some unknown reason, our wscript file now works in Windows Scheduler.